# HTML canvas: How to achieve dropshadow on clipped object?

Tags: html, canvas, clipping, dropshadow

I am trying to draw a dropshadow on a clipped image.

```
function drawCircle(ctx,w,h) {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.ellipse(w/2, h/2, w/2, h/2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
   //ctx.fill(); // This helps, but not suitable for transparent images!
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('c');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const img = new Image();
img.onload = () => {
   // Draw ellipse & clip (removing these 2 lines makes the dropshadow appear)
   drawCircle(ctx, img.width,img.height);
   ctx.clip();

   ctx.shadowOffsetX = 4;
   ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;
   ctx.shadowBlur = 4;
   ctx.shadowColor = '#000';
   ctx.clip();

   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/NdrmFsr.jpg';
```

Without clipping, the image on the canvas has a very visible drop shadow.
With clipping applied, the drop shadow is not visible.
What do I need to change to make the drop shadow visible on a clipped image?

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/av01d/xdemLs2u/

Answer (score 0):

Using the css property `filter`

```
filter: drop-shadow(10px 6px 3px rgba(50, 50, 0, 1));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nj2rpxz6/

Here is [the mozzila doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow()) about the `drop-shadow()` CSS function

Edit :

Here is how you can [add css with Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement) :

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('c');
canvas.style.filter = "drop-shadow(10px 6px 3px rgba(50, 50, 0, 1))"
```

Comment: In my context (fabric.js), CSS is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: What are you talking about ? What is fabric.js ? I have only added css. to your code ^^

Comment: What I meant is that I am looking for a non-CSS solution to this problem. I need the drop-shadow to appear on the canvas itself. And I've found one, see my comment posted on 2022-01-18.

Comment: Ok understand, anyway you could have use style directly in the canvas tag. I have updated my answer to teach you how to add css through Javascript

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. Draw the clipped object on a temporary canvas, then draw that canvas with shadow applied to the main canvas.

```
function drawCircle(ctx,w,h) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.ellipse(w/2, h/2, w/2, h/2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.onload = () => {
    ctx.save();
    drawCircle(ctx, img.width,img.height);
    ctx.clip();

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();

    const canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas'), ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
    canvas2.width = canvas.width; canvas2.height = canvas.height;

    ctx2.shadowOffsetX = 4;
    ctx2.shadowOffsetY = 4;
    ctx2.shadowBlur = 4;
    ctx2.shadowColor = '#000';

    ctx2.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
    //ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(canvas2,0,0);
}
img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/NdrmFsr.jpg';
```